# Memory reserved according to the defined field size or just the size of the data inside?

Tags: hana

In HANA, there's a column of type `NVARCHAR(4000)` with value `ThisISaString`, is the RAM that is being used = 4000 or 13?

If it reserves 4000, then this space could really add up when you have a lot of records.

I am trying to decide how big I should make my text fields.

Comment: You can only get theoretical answers here, seeing SAP HANA isn't open source and implementation detail isn't known to anyone but its developers (maybe they're around here). In theory, variable-length columns reserve length of data (13 in your case) + number of bytes required to store column length definition. To save value of `4000`, you need 2 bytes (1 byte will save decimal integer up to 255), therefore the theoretical requirement would be 15 bytes for your string. Now, whether that holds true for SAP HANA - only the authors know.

Answer (score 2):

What I make of your question in its current form is how SAP HANA handles variable length strings when it comes to presenting it to the client (I take from your intention to reserve a buffer. 
Thus, I'm not going to discuss what happens inside of HANA when you enter a value into a table - this is rather complex and depends on the table type used (column, row, external, temporary...)

So, for the client application, a `(N)VARCHAR`
will result in a string with the length of the stored value, i.e. no padding (with spaces at the end) will happen.